# AngularJS Minfication Error with $provide.decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, hashbang, angularjs-decorator

I have the following code (to force hashbang in the urls) in my app.config which is creating issues in minification:

```
app.config(["$provide", function ($provide) {
    ..
    $provide.decorator('$sniffer', function ($delegate) {
        $delegate.history = false;
            return $delegate;
    });

}]);
```

I know it's got something to do with DI and I have defined "$provide" not sure what else needs to be done. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `$delegate` as function argument might be an issue

Comment: Make sure you do that everywhere to avoid errors while minification :)

Answer (score 4):

Check with this

```
app.config(["$provide", function ($provide) {
    ..
    $provide.decorator('$sniffer', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        $delegate.history = false;
            return $delegate;
    }]);

}]);
```